# Hibernate BatchSize does not affect count of queries being executed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpql

I have two entities (`Parent` and `Child`) related through a one-to-many relation. The choice of `BatchSize` for the relationship seems to have no effect on how the `Parent` and related `Child` entities are fetched.

I tried to check the queries being executed when fetching a particular `Parent` entity (which has at least 3 `Child` entities related to it). With `@BatchSize(size = 1)` and `@BatchSize(size = 3)`, I observed the following single query being executed to fetch the children.

```sql
Hibernate: select children0_.p_id as p_id6_4_1_, children0_.c_id as c_id1_4_1_, children0_.c_id as c_id1_4_0_, children0_.created_at as created_2_4_0_, children0_.updated_at as updated_3_4_0_, children0_.version as version4_4_0_, children0_.child_name as child_na5_4_0_, children0_.p_id as p_id6_4_0_ from assure_child children0_ where children0_.p_id=?
```

As per the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/BatchSize.html), since BatchSize defines the size for batch loading of collections or lazy entities, shouldn't 3 or more queries be executed when fetching the children when BatchSize is 1?

Here is how the relationship looks for reference:

```java
// Parent.java
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent")
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@BatchSize(size = 3)
private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>(0);

// Child.java
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name = "p_id", nullable = false)
@JsonIgnore
private Parent parent;
```